# Create Thread Other than Thread Or Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to know that how to create Thread Object other than Extending Thread Class or Implementing Runnable Interface.

This Question was ask in One of my Interview.

Thanks

Comment: `Thread thread = new Thread();` You are not extending it, or implementing Runnable. In return you still get a Thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.util.concurrent.Executors.newThreadPool(1).submit(Callable)` will create a thread. The Callable implementation you submit will be run in that thread and a Future returned.

Answer (score 1):

Ever since Java 1.5, you should not create threads manually, you should use high level concurrency tools (see for example [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) Item 68: Prefer executors and tasks to threads).

See the [Executors page of the Oracle Concurrency trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) or better yet, read [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create a Java thread without creating an instance of the `Thread` class or, an instance of some class that extends `Thread`...

...But that doesn't mean that *your* code has to create the new `Thread` instance.  There are various library classes that create and use threads on your behalf (e.g., `ThreadPoolExecutor`, the `java.util.stream` package, etc.)